# Alternative to Dynamic Includes In Jade

Tags: templates, dynamic, express, include, pug

What is an alternative solution to trying to use dynamic includes using express + jade? Here is what I'm trying to do with the following setup:

- routes

  - index.js
  - widgets.js
- views

  - widgets

    - widget1.jade
  - index.jade
  - widget.jade
- app.js

In app.js, I specify the following route:

`app.get('/widgets/:widget', widgets.widgets);`

In my widgets route, widgets.js I have:

`exports.widgets = function(req, res){res.render('widgets/' + req.params.widget);};`

This gives me the ability to view a widget on its own by browsing to /widgets/widget1. This works great.  I can also include a widget in another view like this

```
include widgets/widget1
```

This works great too. However, I now want to add widget2 and I want to sometimes show widget1 and sometimes show widget2 within another page. I had hoped to pass a variableWidgetName into the view and then reference it like this:

```
include widgets/#{variableWidgetName}
```

This fails. When I try to access page, I get a 500 error stating that no such file or directory views\widgets#{variableWidgetName}.jade exists. Clearly I cannot reference variables for includes.

What other options do I have. If this is a limitation in Jade, is there a different approach that I should be using? I've thought of loading the widget via ajax but hoped for a better solution using jade or express.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: **This does not work**. What does that exactly mean? Any errors? Unwanted/unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `partial` instead of include.

Here is what works for me (I use harpjs.com with jade, which uses "jade": "0.35.0"):

`` - var name = "something"
!= partial('./'+name+'/hello.md')` ``